# How to combine lists in csv output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to BS4 and python.
For a project i am trying to get some real estate data.
i made my code so that is get two lists.

my challege is to combine te data in the output.

can any one help me please?
ty

ps: any tips on more efficiënt code are welkom.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#open('output.csv', 'w').close()
import re
import time
import requests
from itertools import chain
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/907133/Pythonstuff/chromedriver')
browser.set_window_position(0,0)


def jaap_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p{}'.format(page)
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        #input('Press Enter after bypassing Captcha')
        #print(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        info = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'property-info'})
        inside = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'property-inner'},{'href'})
        #print(inside)
        for huis in info:
            #locatie = huis.find('div')
            #locatie = ' '.join(locatie.get_text(separator='\r\n', strip=True).split()[:-1]) 
            #locatie = huis.find('h2')
            #locatie = ' '.join(locatie.get_text(separator='\r\n', strip=True).split())
            street = huis.find('h2')
            street = ' '.join(street.get_text(separator='\r\n', strip=True).split()[:+3])  
            #sep by newline, strip whitespace, then split to get the last 3 elements to cut out, then rejoin
            address = huis.find('div')
            address = address.find('div').text.strip()
            price = huis.find('div', {'class': 'price-info'})
            price = price.find('div').text.strip()
            price = re.findall(r'\d', price)
            price = ''.join(price)
            pricetag = huis.find('div', {'class': 'property-price'})
            pricetag = pricetag.find('span').text.strip()
            l1 = ('{},{},{},{}'.format(street, address, price, pricetag))
            #print('{},{},{},{}'.format(street, address, price, pricetag))
            out = open('output.csv', 'w')
            saveFile = open('output.csv', 'a')
            saveFile.write(street + "," + address + "," + price + "," + pricetag + '\n')
            #print (list1)
        for items in inside:
            href = items.get('href')
            #print (href)
            url1 = href.format(page)
            browser.get(url1)
            kenmerken = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
            details = kenmerken.find_all ('div', {'class':'detail-tab-content kenmerken'})
            try:
                tr = details[0].find_all ('td', {'class': 'value'})
            except IndexError:
                size_space = 'Unknown'
            #print (tr)
            for inhoud in tr:
                soort = tr[0].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                bouwjaar = tr[1].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                woonoppervlakte = tr[2].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                inhoud = tr[3].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                perceel = tr[4].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
            l2 = ('{},{},{},{},{}'.format(soort, bouwjaar, woonoppervlakte, inhoud, perceel))
            #print('{},{},{},{},{}'.format(soort, bouwjaar, woonoppervlakte, inhoud, perceel))   
            saveFile = open('output.csv', 'a')
            saveFile.write(soort+ "," + bouwjaar+ "," + woonoppervlakte + "," + inhoud + "," + perceel + '\n')
            saveFile.close()
            #output = list(chain(list1,list2))
            #print (output)
        page += 1       

    #output = list(chain(list1,list2))
    #print (output)
            #kenmerken = inside.find_all ('a', {'class': 'href'})
            #print (href)
            #print (details)
            #print('{},{},{},{}'.format(street, address, price, pricetag))
            #saveFile = open('jaap.csv', 'a')
            #saveFile.write(street + "," + address + "," +  price + "," + pricetag + '\n')
            #saveFile.close()


jaap_spider(1)
```

Comment: Always fun to scrape house sale data ;-). I would probably change your lists into a Pandas DataFrame. You can then further analyse it in Pandas if you want, or export it to CSV.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial to learn that?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials online for the basics of Pandas. I think for example DataCamp had a good (free) introduction course.

Comment: By the way, for efficiency sake: A lot (or all?) of the information you seem to be requesting is already available in the "overview" page. That way you can get the basic info on 30 houses per webpage. I made a script a few years back that could scrape all houses on Jaap in about 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Ty for the adjustment, keeps me going again!

The data iam most intrested in is the lot size, size of the house and the sort of house.
i coudn't find this in de code on the first page, maybe it is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code doesn't actually seem to make two lists. But asuming that you would make a list of lists for `l1` out of `for huis in info:` and a list of lists `l2` from `for items in inside:`, what you could do to combine two lists of lists is: `outputlist = [a + b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]`.

I incorporated that, plus a conversion to a Pandas DataFrame and an export to csv in the adapted code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import pandas as pd

#browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/907133/Pythonstuff/chromedriver')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\NLNIEH\.spyder-py3\chromedriver.exe')
browser.set_window_position(0,0)

def jaap_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p{}'.format(page)
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        info = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'property-info'})
        inside = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'property-inner'},{'href'})

        # Make empty lists with header lines
        outputlist_l1 = [['street', 'address', 'price', 'pricetag']]
        outputlist_l2 = [['soort', 'bouwjaar', 'woonoppervlakte', 'inhoud', 'perceel']]

        for huis in info:
            street = huis.find('h2')
            street = ' '.join(street.get_text(separator='\r\n', strip=True).split()[:+3])  
            address = huis.find('div')
            address = address.find('div').text.strip()
            price = huis.find('div', {'class': 'price-info'})
            price = price.find('div').text.strip()
            price = re.findall(r'\d', price)
            price = ''.join(price)
            pricetag = huis.find('div', {'class': 'property-price'})
            pricetag = pricetag.find('span').text.strip()
            outputlist_l1.append([street, address, price, pricetag])

        for items in inside:
            href = items.get('href')
            url1 = href.format(page)
            browser.get(url1)
            kenmerken = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
            details = kenmerken.find_all ('div', {'class':'detail-tab-content kenmerken'})
            try:
                tr = details[0].find_all ('td', {'class': 'value'})
            except IndexError:
                size_space = 'Unknown'

            for inhoud in tr:
                soort = tr[0].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                bouwjaar = tr[1].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                woonoppervlakte = tr[2].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                inhoud = tr[3].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
                perceel = tr[4].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
            l2 = ('{},{},{},{},{}'.format(soort, bouwjaar, woonoppervlakte, inhoud, perceel))
            outputlist_l2.append([soort, bouwjaar, woonoppervlakte, inhoud, perceel])

        page += 1    
    # Merge outputlist_l1 with outputlist_l2
    outputlist = [a + b for a, b in zip(outputlist_l1, outputlist_l2)]

    # transform to Pandas dataframe and export as csv
    df = pd.DataFrame(outputlist[1:], columns=outputlist[0])
    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

jaap_spider(1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle the cookies that pop up after you scrap the 6 or 7th page?
it looks like the pop ups succesfully disrupt the output in the csv file.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Cookies that pop up"? Do you mean the cookies message? With your code, I get that at the first page and immediatly click it away and don't have it anymore (but I only tried the exact code above). In my own old script, I didn't use Selenium, but only urllib I think. I didn't get cookies with that.

Comment: On the first page you can click it away, but with me it pop up again when the crawler reaches page 7 or more.

Can i rebuild to urllid code?

Comment: Update: i see that in the way the df.to.csv is formatted it overwrites the CSV file every time with the output of the last page scraped.
so the output onlys consists of the last page, while it suppose that is would stack the date in the CSV file

Comment: It writes the CSV-file at the end of the function. Pandas can't update a csv-file (you would have to first read the excisting csv into a dataframe and than join that one with your new dataframe and export it again to csv). But right now, your function isn't set up to be run multiple times right? Otherwise, just return the dataframe at the end of your function and concatenate or join it with the dataframe from the previous function call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use csv for writing list in csv file.

```
import csv

def write_list_in_file(filepath, output):
    with open(filepath, 'a') as outtsv:
        tuple_writer = csv.writer(outtsv, delimiter=',')
        tuple_writer.writerow(output)
```